# Script on Website Clearing Console, how can i stop it?

Tags: html, google-chrome, console, opera

So I'm working on a chrome extension and I need to see what my script is logging in the site but one of the websites script is clearing the console? Is There an option to turn off the script or remove its permissions to clear console.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome, if you click on Console settings icon there is an option called "Preserve log", and although the script calls the clear method, the log remains.